# Bash: Why elif condition didn't return true

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash snippet as follows but I don't know why the elif statement didn't work, here is the snippet:

```
NUMBER1=42
NUMBER2=1
echo "    \$NUMBER1=$NUMBER1 \$NUMBER2=$NUMBER2"
if [ $NUMBER1 == $NUMBER1 ]; then
    echo "    [ \$NUMBER1 == \$NUMBER1 ] is true"
elif [ $NUMBER1 != $NUMBER2 ]; then
    echo "    [ \$NUMBER1 != \$NUMBER2 ] is true"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in your first condition, you are compare same variable in that case `elif` will never be true.

(OP's code):

```
if [ $NUMBER1 == $NUMBER1 ]; then
```

should be `if [ $NUMBER1 == $NUMBER2 ]; then`

```
NUMBER1=42
NUMBER2=1
echo "    \$NUMBER1=$NUMBER1 \$NUMBER2=$NUMBER2"
if [ $NUMBER1 == $NUMBER2 ]; then
    echo "    [ \$NUMBER1 == \$NUMBER2 ] is true"
elif [ $NUMBER1 != $NUMBER2 ]; then
    echo "    [ \$NUMBER1 != \$NUMBER2 ] is true"
fi
```